# Stride and buffersize when processing images

Tags: c#, directshow

On MSDN I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the definition of the image stride. In short it is the width in bytes of one line in the buffer.

Now I have an RGB image in a similar buffer and I have been given the stride and the image width in pixels, and I want to know how much padding bytes there have been added.

Is this simply stride - 3 * imagewidth since I have 3 bytes (RGB) per pixel?

```
unsafe private void setPrevFrame(IntPtr pBuffer)
    {
        prevFrame = new byte[m_videoWidth, m_videoHeight, 3];
        Byte* b = (byte*) pBuffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_videoWidth; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_videoHeight; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    prevFrame[i,j,k] = *b;
                    b++;
                }
            }
            b += (m_stride - 3 * m_videoHeight);
        }
    }
```

It's the last line of code I'm not sure about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stride will be padded to a 4 byte boundary:

So if your image width is `W` and it is 3 bytes per pixel:

```
int strideWidth = ((W * 3) - 1) / 4 * 4 + 4; 
//or simply
int strideWidth = Math.Abs(bData.Stride);

//and so
int padding = strideWidth - W * 3;
```

If you are using the [`.Stride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `BitmapData` object, you must `Abs` that value because it may be negative.

Following your edit of the question:

There is no need for you to know the padding in order to iterate all the bytes of the image:

```
unsafe private void setPrevFrame(IntPtr pBuffer)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m_videoHeight; j++)
    {
        b = scan0 + j * stride; //the first byte of the first pixel of the row
        for (int i = 0; i < m_videoWidth; i++)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Your previous method will also fail on bottom-up images, as described in the MSDN link you posted.

Comment: so W*3 + 3 ? and it states that for 2 images of the same pixel size can have different strides, so shouldn't that variable be incorporated?

Comment: Why W*3+3 ? I think they mean 2 images with different bytes per pixel. AFAIK stride is padded to a 4 byte boundary, so it should be identical for images of similar width and bytes per pixel. Keep in mind stride may also be negative, which indicates that the image is arranged bottom-up.

Comment: for performance reasons, I make use of a Byte* buffer, and I need to go through all pixels. So I have 3 forloops (one for height, one for width and one for RGB) where I do: Pointer += m_stride - 3 * m_height

With your explenation, I see this is a wrong approach but I'm not quite sure how to solve the problem then, if the image can be upsidedown...

Comment: Sorry, one fix. The outer loop should be the height of course, not the width.