# Garbled display of bitmap data

Tags: c++, bitmap, directshow

This is my first posting, so please bear with me.
I am pretty new to Directshow and C++ programming but after spending hours after hours looking for this specific answer, I cannot help but asking my question here.

I am working on Viveks famous  VCam sample. It is derived from the Directshow Pushsource sample so i thought it should be workable to display a bmp which the Pushsource Sample displays fine.

According to this source https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/11560cfc-41cc-4586-ada5-c1847b27b3f6/vcamax-input?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment the magic happens in the FillBuffer method. So I followed the Pushsource sample accordingly to load a bitmap but all I get is garbled output similar as it is shown here: [ISampleGrabber::BufferCB to IplImage; display in OpenCV shows garbled image - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902048/isamplegrabberbuffercb-to-iplimage-display-in-opencv-shows-garbled-image-c?rq=1)

So I am doing something wrong and went through all steps of the samples again and again but cannot see much difference.
Here is what I do:
1. Load a bitmap
2. Copy the bitmap into a buffer
3. Copying the buffer into the FillBuffer method with memcpy.

But what I get is this compared to this.

[original and distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w7XE.png)

The output looks different with every bitmap I use, so I can see that the data changes with the images. But for some reason it does not get recognized as bitmap.

I am completely out of ideas. So I would be glad to receive some suggestions what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That's a classic one. You have problems wit the image stride: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054011/399561

Comment: Sadly I cannot accept your comment as answer. I believe it was kind of a stride issue caused by fixed widths and heights of the media type.
When I set dimensions manually the image displays without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a classic one. You have problems wit the [image stride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx) in your MediaType. Here is a question with the same problem: [stackoverflow.com/a/20054011/399561](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20054011/399561)